# Error: Could not find or load main class Neon Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I'm trying to execute carel programs based on CSA106a Stanford class videos available on YouTube.

I've downloaded the jar and related files, imported the whole project into Neon Eclipse and am trying to run.

While clicking "run", I get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class (default package).CheckerboardKarel

*Note:* other programs that I have created in Neon from scratch are working fine (not imported ones). Please help.

I've attached the screenshots as well.

[image: here]

[image: here]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure, but I think there might not be a "main" function in what you downloaded. In order for a java program to run the class you are running needs to have a main function. it should look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. But I m trying to create a program like explain in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LoKDDRlfZc&t=526s......( between14 to 20 mins ).